# How to create a numbered alert on a button with either HTML5, jQuery, PHP, or JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a button in HTML linked to a page with features like emails. I'm trying to figure out how to alert the user by using a number on my button that'll tell the user how many messages they have before they click on the button to view them. It's pretty much an alert without a popup. I prefer the programming languages to be either HTML5, jQuery, PHP, or JavaScript if possible.

The wording doesn't have to match mine, I just need an example on how to do that alert I asked for. Thanks for your help in advance!

Here's an example of my button:

```
<form method = "link" action = "messages.html">
    <input type = "submit" value = "Messages">
</form>
```

Comment: HTML5 isn't a programming language, nor is jQuery (javascript is the language, but jQuery is a library). PHP would only be used to generate the javascript that would do it. What exactly is it that you want? You want the button to display the number of messages or something else?

Comment: Well I suppose in the page load you would need to make a call to the 'data' e.g. MYSQL and get a count of the nuber of records and then append that number to the text of your button.  That's very high level but all I can suggest with the limited information you have given.

Comment: I guess the best way to describe what I'm asking is like on the iPhone email app, if you have 4 emails, a number 4 with a red circle around it will show up on the button that links to your email app. That's what I'm wanting is that number to show up on the side of my button. I'm aware html5 and jQuery isn't a programming language but wasn't sure if they may of had a feature for it. I knew I'd need either a javascript or php function for it but wasn't sure how get the number feature on the button.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on B7ackAnge7z answer.

I would always suggest against using inline javascript. Why? Because it is awful to edit in the future, which you inevitably will need to.

So my suggestion would be to make a function that does this for you.

Heres the jsfiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/CSZ9L/

And here is the code.

The html

```
<input class="messageBox" type="submit" value="Messages" data-message="Heres the message" />​
```

The javascript, including jQuery

```
$(".messageBox").click(function() {
 alert($(this).attr("data-message"));
});​
```

You can set a class of messageBox to any item you want to alert a message for. Then using php you can fill the data-message attribute with your message. The javascript will handle the rest.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type = "submit" value = "You have <?php echo getNumMessages(); ?> new mail messages. yayyyyyyyy i got mail yayyy...">
```

php function

```
function getNumMessages() {
    return 5;
}
```

Comment: 42... The random number is always 42! ;)

Comment: @Andreas: Yes it is... Randall just forgot the 2... ;)

Comment: if you wish to improve my post, make the button play this audio clip http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Gj8bin3vlQ

Answer (score 0):

To show an alert message use `onclick`:

```
<input type="submit" value="Messages" onclick="alert('hello world!')" />
```